# Razor template error

Tags: razormediator

I'm working with razor templates, I have two `if`'s inside a `foreach`.

I've attached the simple code. But when I use Template Builder razor doesn't interpret the second if (it's like a text for Razor). If I add a `@` before the `if`, I get an error.

```
@foreach (var cp in ComponentPresentations) {
    if (cp.Template.Title == "Identification") {                          
        <title>@cp.Component.titlePage</title>

        <head>
            @* THE PROBLEM IS HERE *@
            if (cp.Component.facebook.title != null) {
                <meta property="og:title" content="@cp.Component.facebook.title" >
            }  
        </head>
    }
}
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: And the error is??????

Comment: Adding a @ in front of the if should work - what error do you get? It may be getting confused by the lack of closing meta tag

Comment: Think that's it Will. <text><meta....></text> should fix it then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an @ before the if - Razor treats everything as markup until it encounters an @, then it treats it as code, until it finds something it thinks is markup (like an HTML tag) until it finds something like code again (like a closing HTML tag and then a closing brace }). The error you get is probably as Razor doesn't find a closing `</meta>` tag, so gets a bit confused as to whether the closing brace is markup or code. You can fix this by closing the meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="@cp.Component.facebook.title" />
```

Or, like Dom suggests using a `<text/>` element

```
<text><meta property="og:title" content="@cp.Component.facebook.title"></text>
```